# How does this generator returns 3?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

While trying to understand generator, instead of following:

```
function* powerSeries(number,power) {
  let base = number;
  while (true) {
    yield Math.pow(base, power);
    base++
  }
}

let n = powerSeries(3,2)
n.next() // value: 9
n.next() // value: 16
...
```

I tried like:

```
function* powerSeries(number,power) {
  let base = number;
  yield Math.pow(base, power);
  return base++ // was trying to understand what happens if using return
}

let n = powerSeries(3,2)
n.next() // value: 9
n.next() // value: 3 But how ????
```

I can understand post increment isn't being done because it's not inside a loop. So, it stays 3 for base. But how is it becoming 1 for power so it results in 3?

**Acknowledged:**
Thank you everyone. I was confused that if I use return statement then it would still call yield.

Comment: You _return_ `base`, not `Math.pow(base, power)` and `base === 3`. There is no power of 1; nothing is being exponentiated at the second `.next`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm knowingly doing that. And I already agree in my question that base is 3 as it's not inside loop. But how power is becoming 1?

Comment: Read my edited comment.

Comment: I'm curious about what you expected the result to be instead of 3. Did you expect 4? If so, recall that `a++` has a "return value" of `a`, and then increments `a` as a side effect. `++a` increments before returning.

Comment: Why do you think `power` is becoming 1? It's still 2, but after the single `yield` statement (which produced the 9 you saw) it's never used again.

Comment: ah, you mean yield is not being used but just return statement?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I was still expecting to result in 9. (3,2)

Comment: @gulcy _“Ah, you mean yield is not being used but just return statement?”_ — Yes, of course. Why would `yield` be executed again? Try `yield ["yield", Math.pow(base, power)]; return ["return", base++]` instead. Do you see two `yield`s? No; you get `["yield", 9]` and `["return", 3]`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks. I got it now.

Comment: I am not sure why I get downvotes always. I'm just beginner in javascript and trying to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield):

> ### [Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield#Description)
>
> [...]
>
> A [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement is reached. In this case, execution of the generator ends and an `IteratorResult` is returned to the caller in which the `value` is the value specified by the `return` statement and done is `true`.

```js
function* powerSeries(number,power) {
  let base = number;
  yield Math.pow(base, power);
  return base++ // was trying to understand what happens if using return
}

let n = powerSeries(3,2)
console.log(n.next().value); // 9
console.log(n.next().value); // 3
console.log(n.next().value); // undefined
```

Comment: Thanks. I get it fully now.